# Firebase functions pubsub trigger: subscribe to more than 1 event?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

So the usual way to write a pubsub triggered function is

```
exports.someFunction = functions.pubsub.topic('topicName').onPublish(message => {})
```

What if you want to re-use the same code in the function `someFunction` for another event? I can't seem to find any mentions of firebase functions being able to subscribe to more than 1 event at a time.

Or is this considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to export one function for each topic.  If you want to reuse the code, you can simply make a normal JavaScript function with the shared logic.

```
exports.topic1 = functions.pubsub.topic('topic1')
    .onPublish(message => handleMessage(message))
exports.topic2 = functions.pubsub.topic('topic2')
    .onPublish(message => handleMessage(message))

function handleMessage(message) {
    // your shared logic here
}
```